# M1 Mac returns OSError: Library not loaded

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1, oserror

I am trying to import forecasting models from the darts package using `from darts.models import ExponentialSmoothing` and the following error is returned:

```
OSError: dlopen(/Users/sp/opt/anaconda3/envs/august/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/sp/opt/anaconda3/envs/august/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file)
```

I have seen a lot of people have the same issue when installing `LightGBM` and have tried all those fixes. I have tried `brew install libomp`, I have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda, I have used different environments, I have installed `gcc` and `cmake` and nothing has worked. I have a MacBook Pro with an M1 chip and am using Spyder with Anaconda. Does anyone have an answer to this?

My code, which is taken directly from the darts package site, and its output is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

import darts

from darts import TimeSeries

# Read a pandas DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/sp/Documents/Skripsie/airline-passenger-traffic.csv')

# Create a TimeSeries, specifying the time and value columns

series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df, '1949-01', '112')

# Set aside the last 36 months as a validation series

train, val = series[:-36], series[-36:]

from darts.models import ExponentialSmoothing
```

The Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/var/folders/51/7qn6p5813zd3dw8p2c_t3btr0000gn/T/ipykernel_68567/3838417146.py", line 1, in <module>
    from darts.models import ExponentialSmoothing

  File "/Users/sp/opt/anaconda3/envs/august/lib/python3.9/site-packages/darts/models/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    from darts.models.forecasting.gradient_boosted_model import LightGBMModel

  File "/Users/sp/opt/anaconda3/envs/august/lib/python3.9/site-packages/darts/models/forecasting/gradient_boosted_model.py", line 13, in <module>
    import lightgbm as lgb

  File "/Users/sp/opt/anaconda3/envs/august/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .basic import Booster, Dataset, Sequence, register_logger

  File "/Users/sp/opt/anaconda3/envs/august/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 110, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()

  File "/Users/sp/opt/anaconda3/envs/august/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 101, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])

  File "/Users/sp/opt/anaconda3/envs/august/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 460, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)

  File "/Users/sp/opt/anaconda3/envs/august/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 382, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: dlopen(/Users/sp/opt/anaconda3/envs/august/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/sp/opt/anaconda3/envs/august/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file)
```

Answer (score 2):

sjp00,

Your post could have been from me almost verbatim. I went through a very similar process. After pulling my hair out, this is what worked. **TL;DR is that for Darts to work with LightGBM on an apple M1 computer conda-forge needs to be used**. Default conda will not work (but may at a future date).

Reading this issue helped clarify the situation, https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/4843

specifically, StrikerRUS's comment:

> "If I understood correctly, default conda channels lack support of
> macOS-arm64 packages."(https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/4843#issuecomment-1012313487)

and

> One difference could be that I'm using Conda instead of miniconda?
>
> Yeah! That is my main assumption! I believe that LightGBM is being
> compiled for arm64 architecture but conda (and Python) is x64-based
> and is run via Rosetta 2 translation. So architecture mismatch
> happens.

(https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/4843#issuecomment-1061332231)

On my laptop which is a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021), with an Apple M1 Pro chip, and macOS Monterey Version 12.5.1 installed and the following conda setup:

> conda info
>
> ```
>  active environment : lightgbm_test_env
> active env location : /Users/bhudson/opt/anaconda3/envs/lightgbm_test_env
>         shell level : 2
>    user config file : /Users/bhudson/.condarc  populated config files : /Users/bhudson/.condarc
>       conda version : 4.14.0
> conda-build version : 3.21.9
>      python version : 3.9.7.final.0
>    virtual packages : __osx=10.16=0
>                       __unix=0=0
>                       __archspec=1=x86_64
>    base environment : /Users/bhudson/opt/anaconda3  (writable)
>   conda av data dir : /Users/bhudson/opt/anaconda3/etc/conda   conda av metadata url : None
>        channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
>                       https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>       package cache : /Users/bhudson/opt/anaconda3/pkgs
>                       /Users/bhudson/.conda/pkgs
>    envs directories : /Users/bhudson/opt/anaconda3/envs
>                       /Users/bhudson/.conda/envs
>            platform : osx-64
>          user-agent : conda/4.14.0 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.9.7 Darwin/21.6.0 OSX/10.16
>             UID:GID : 501:20
>          netrc file : None
>        offline mode : False
> ```

This is what finally worked for me. First make and activate a clean python 3.9 environment

```
conda create -n lightgbm_test_env python=3.9
conda activate lightgbm_test_env
```

Make sure that conda forge is added as a channel (and that is prioritized)

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

Then install all of U8Darts with LightGBM at the same time.

```
conda install -c conda-forge -c pytorch u8darts-all lightgbm
```

The "-c conda-forge" flag may not be strictly necessary, but I left it in for extra redundancy.

Comment: And if my project install is poetry-based? I am worrind that using conda-forge would create an unfortunate mix

Answer (score 0):

You should install OpenMP according to [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/lightgbm/).

It can be done with the following command:

```
brew install libomp
```

This solved my problem, I hope it will help someone else